# MySQL - advice about multiple language DB

Tags: mysql

I need a little help with creating a database for a multiple language web site. I have a feeling that I am creating a monster. So any advice will be very helpful. I have two tables for the articles.

This table contains data that will be the same for every language:

```
article

id_article
images
date_created
date_start
date_end
```

This table contains data that is different - Text in English is not the same as the text in German.

```
article_info

article_id
title
text
info
category_id
lang_id
```

Idea behind this is that one article can be in multiple different languages. Is this a good way of building the tables or am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me, and I think that's how it is handled in most cases (parent record => child records with language specifics). The fun part is going to come with administering the data. Do you create a separate admin for each language, or have a bunch of boxes for each language all on one big form?

Comment: @Sam I don't quite understand the question but in short - I am using CodeIgniter as project framework and when user comes to the site, global session variable is set, and based on that query is done (I wrote a function to determine country of user and user can also change language). As for the admin part of the web site - by default all article are listed and if there is need to list articles by language, admin can do that.

Comment: category_id? It seems to me that it must be on the article table. Anyway, article and article_info table is a good way to handle this.

Comment: @Nathan I guess I can do that - I am still in duo language mode (categories doesn't have same name but it is the same category in both languages). Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this design, in which an article can have one or more renderings in different languages, will work well.  I've worked on a similar system, where the multiple languages were an afterthought.  On that system, the primary language (EN-us usually) had columns in the article table.  This is better.

One thing to think about:  You may, or may not, want to be able to store an article's summary data such as titles, subjects, keywords, and possibly an abstract in multiple languages even if you don't possess a translation for the whole article.  So, instead of article_info, you may want separate tables for title_info, text_info, keyword_info, and so forth, each with a lang_id key.

Pay attention to your character set (utf8 is a good choice) and collation.  Your default collation should be utf8_general_ci, but your

```
 ORDER BY xxx COLLATE collation
```

may need to be set user-by-user based on a user-preference setting. For example, `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` won't do the right thing for Spanish-language titles in which n and ñ are different letters.

Comment: For the moment this is duo language web site and articles must exist in both language, but this is very good advice if site goes global :) (I guess I would it would be harder to change things latter on). Thank you for the advice :)